# Получение идентификатора фотографии в альбоме для метода Likes.Add vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api

Нужно получить все ID фотографий в альбоме, для метода likes.Add.
Писал в тех поддержку, игнорят 2 день. Подскажите метод.

Comment: ну так бери все идентификаторы из альбома https://vk.com/dev/photos.get , фильтруй и применяй like.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам использовать likes.add (он только добавляет указанный объект в список "мне нравится")?

Используйте его параметр item_id в качестве идентификатора для вывода нужного альбома через метод photos.get. Далее в массиве items ищете id нужных вам фотографий.